# Wordpress Formatting Issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am building a website using a theme I bought before I knew the developer has been missing for a few months now.
The theme has an area that you can ad ads. Well when I added the code there seems to be an overlapping problem.
Here is a picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1EIw.png [1] I am ok with code I guess, as I can figures tuff out 9/10 times by looking at the page source. But I have been trying to figure this out for some time.
If anyone can fix it I will forever be in your debt. So basically fix it for me and I will offer you my firstborn!
-Zack

And here is what the code looks like from a pagesource in chrome. This is the area with the bottom ad banner in it.

```
  </div>

              <div class="ad728"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Bottom Banner -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1255317832671"
     data-ad-slot="586143129"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>

</section>

<section class="container main border-radius">

  <div class="padding-both">

  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div>
      <div class="description">
        <div class="title-special border-radius" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <div class="padding-10">
            Game description          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-10">
```

Comment: First guess would be... there's some weird floating going on with your advertisement. Maybe there needs to be a clear:both at the end of the div containing the ad? I dunno... just a guess, check floating stuff

Comment: Alright I will take a look!

Comment: i thing you missed put some closing tag like </div>,</table>...

Comment: this one fixed using css please add on your style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using css :

```
 .ad728{
          clear:both;
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool, so pardon me for being awful. Do i need to just add that line of code in my CSS?

Comment: line no 77 or you can add bellow for particular class css.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a dev link?

Could just inspect the code and give an answer